# How to find the exact countries in below situation

Tags: google-sheets-formula

if US/CA/NL/HK is available(all four countries) in CA/ US/ MX/ AU/ IN/ JP/ NZ/ SG/ TW/ AT/ BE/ CZ/ DK/ EE/ FR/ DE/ HU/ IE/ IT/ LV/ LT/ NL/ NO/ PL/ PT/ RO/ SK/ ES/ SE/ CH/ GB then give Yes or else give No.

Can someone help me with the formula in google sheet

I have tried it with find formula but unable to do.

Comment: Try `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(FIND("US",A1)),ISNUMBER(FIND("CA",A1)),ISNUMBER(FIND("NL",A1)),ISNUMBER(FIND("HK",A1))), "Yes", "No")` or `=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*US*")+COUNTIF(A1,"*CA*")+COUNTIF(A1,"*NL*")+COUNTIF(A1,"*HK*")=4,"Yes","No")`

Comment: Hi Ayush, thank you it's working, could you pls tell me how to get rest countries in a list except those 4 (US, NL, CA, HK)

Comment: Welcome! If you want to remove those 4 countries from the list then try `=SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(A1:A, NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A, "US|NL|CA|HK")))), ",")`

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(a,b,if(a="",,let(Σ,split(a,"/ ",0),Δ,split(b,"/"),if(counta(index(ifna(xmatch(Σ,Δ))))=counta(Δ),"YES","NO")))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rama you can use the following formula in Google Sheets to **determine if all four countries (US/CA/NL/HK) are available in the given list of countries**:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,"US",A:A,"CA",A:A,"NL",A:A,"HK")=4,"Yes","No")
```

Assuming the **list of countries is in column A**, this formula counts the number of times "US", "CA", "NL", and "HK" appear in column A using the COUNTIFS function. If all four countries appear exactly 4 times, then the formula returns "Yes"; otherwise, it returns "No".